# button.isHidden to disappear again after being button view(background) is tapped on again

Tags: ios, swift, image

Still new to swift, but was having some fun with storyboard and with hiding and showing buttons. I created a storyboard with an image view that fills the whole view, and a button that lies on top of it called the overView. I also created a button called the searchButton that is on top of the overView. I so far am pretty stoked I got something this easy to work but need some more help. When the user clicks on the screen,(overView button), the searchButton appears. Great! But I want it (searchButton) to disappear once tapped on again. If someone could help me, that would be great. Thanks, here's my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchButton.isHidden = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBOutlet weak var overView: UIButton!
@IBAction func overView(_ sender: Any) {
    searchButton.isHidden = false
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func overView(_ sender: Any) {
    searchButton.isHidden = !searchButton.isHidden
}
```

And if your searchButton is cover overView then try this:

```
@IBAction func onTapSearchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    searchButton.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: worked AlvinZhu will mark it correct when it lets me, thanks!